# Generating functions over a range of numbers

Tags: rust, macros

I'd like to perform some benchmarks over a range of functions that should be bench marked individually.
So I thought I could define a macro that would generate all the functions.

The output for the range `1..10` should look something like this:

```
#[bench]
fn bench1(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(1) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench2(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(2) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench3(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(3) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench4(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(4) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench5(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(5) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench6(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(6) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench7(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(7) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench8(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(8) }); }
#[bench]
fn bench9(b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(9) }); }
```

First I don't know how I can generate the function name `bench$n` in the macro.
The next problem that I'm facing is that the number should be an ident and an expr at the same time, this is because I need to use the same argument in the function name and in the expression for `test_function`. I also thought about an recursive approach to the macro but I really never used macros in Rust before.

How if possible would one implement this macro.

Comment: You might find something useful in the [`Criterion` crate](https://crates.io/crates/criterion).

Comment: A macro could generate this code if you're feeling sufficiently adventurous. It might be easiest to specify individual numbers rather than a range, though, like `#[expand_bench(n=1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9)]` where that defines an `n` that you can use in the expanded tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of the [`duplicate`](https://crates.io/crates/duplicate) and [`paste`](https://crates.io/crates/paste) crates can get you some of what you are looking for:

```rust
use duplicate::duplicate_item;
use paste::paste;

#[duplicate_item(
  num; [1]; [2]; [3]; [4]; [5]; [6]; [7]; [8]; [9];
)]
paste!{
  #[bench]
  fn [< bench num >](b: &mut Bencher) { b.iter(|| { test_function(num) });}
}
```

The above code will expand to your exact code.
`duplicate_item` makes sure to duplicate the function for each integer value you want, while `paste` can concatenate the number with `bench` to generate each function's name.

This will not work using an explicit range like `1..10`, as `duplicate_item` needs to be given each value individually. But as long as your range is manageably small it should be fine. Alternatively, it can also work if you want individual values that don't necessarily follow each other.